# Pure CSS Starburst wheel with gradients

Tags: html, css, gradient

I am attempting to create an animated "starburst wheel" in pure CSS. Here's what I have so far:

http://codepen.io/billdami/pen/qaGNRm

The intended effect is a circle with triangular spokes/rays expanding out from the center, like I have there, but also have the rays be gradients, whose alpha transparency fades out to 0% at the outermost edge (something like [this](http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/299362/366554324/stock-vector-abstract-starburst-sunburst-background-radiating-converging-lines-rays-vector-366554324.jpg)), and that is the part I can't figure out.

I went with the border-width trick to create the triangles as there doesn't seem to be any other real way to create triangles with pure css/html (maybe clip paths?), and I was then going to use `border-image` to add a gradient to it, but that doesn't work because you can't apply a border image to only one side.

Any ideas or suggestions?

edit: clip-path looks like its out as it has no IE support at all...

Comment: Is [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amAJPQ) what you want?

Comment: @Ricky_Ruiz very close! But the rays' gradient needs to fade out to 0% alpha as it gets farther away from the center, so that the content behind the wheel itself is visible. In your example, the wheel is completely opaque.

Comment: I don't have time to post an answer now. But you can get the trisngles with a transform: skewX(75deg) or so. (and letting the overflow hidden of the container get rid of the remining part)

Comment: @vals hmm yeah I thought about trying a `transform: skewX()` to make the triangles, but couldn't figure out how to crop it so that its not just a parallelogram type shape. Would love to see an example of how you would do that (even if its not the entire wheel, just a single triangle) if you have the time! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my solution.

Sorry for the late answer !

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.starbust-wheel {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: spin 8s infinite linear;
}
.starbust-wheel > li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, red 5%, transparent 25%);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(even) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-197deg, blue 2%, transparent 30%);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(1) {
    transform: rotate(18deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotate(36deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(3) {
    transform: rotate(54deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(4) {
    transform: rotate(72deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(5) {
    transform: rotate(90deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(6) {
    transform: rotate(108deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(7) {
    transform: rotate(126deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(8) {
    transform: rotate(144deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(9) {
    transform: rotate(162deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(10) {
    transform: rotate(180deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(11) {
    transform: rotate(198deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(12) {
    transform: rotate(216deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(13) {
    transform: rotate(234deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(14) {
    transform: rotate(252deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(15) {
    transform: rotate(270deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(16) {
    transform: rotate(288deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(17) {
    transform: rotate(306deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(18) {
    transform: rotate(324deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(19) {
    transform: rotate(342deg) skewX(72deg);
}
.starbust-wheel > li:nth-child(20) {
    transform: rotate(360deg)  skewX(72deg);
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
            transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
            transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="starbust-wheel">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

here we go